# Android emulator is upside down in android studio. How to fix tit?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

1.I develop my app in android studio and test on emulator.

2.In manifest i set **screenOrientation="portrait**

3.I set emulator like this picture

[image]

4.When i run may app the 10.1"WXGA is show landscape.

5.When i rotate emulator by numpad 9 my app is show upside down.

6.How to fix it's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's shown upside down, because you set the "portrait" orientation. Change to "sensorPortrait" to support both portrait and reverse portrait (phone upside down).

`"sensorPortrait"   | Portrait orientation, but can be either normal or reverse portrait based on the device sensor. Added in API level 9.`

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html